# Teaching visual tools for visually impaired students?

Tags: teaching, health

I am teaching a module related to data visualization. Thus, of course, most of the tools are visual tools, that is, tools for visualizing summaries of the data.

I have visually impaired students, which makes it really difficult to teach them these tools, as it involves two- and three-dimensional plots and graphs.

Creating an audio substitute for these is very complicated, but of course it is essential to make the teaching material available.

What are the main rules for making this kind of material accessible?

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/78668/teaching-a-blind-student-matlab-programming/78669#78669

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 Thanks, very interesting points.

Comment: This may be of interest: http://iris.grapheel.com/

Comment: In what environment are you working? Do you have a disabilities office that could support you in this?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim All teaching is online due to the pandemic. There is a disabilities department, but they are overwhelmed and not really attending particular issues.

Comment: @astronat Interesting, I wonder how fast can you get a reply.

Comment: @datavis The reason I ask is because you could unfortunately end up putting in a lot of time and doing a bad job (and then all that time would be wasted). When do classes start for you?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim Very good points. They start in September, so there is time to plan ahead. It is going to be a challenging semester ...

Comment: I doubt there is a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

There are physical devices that permit the blind to feel three dimensional graphs. Do a search for something like "haptic graphing device for visually impaired" to see some of the possibilities. They aren't cheap, of course. One of the most interesting, I think, is one designed at [Stanford University](https://www.slashgear.com/tactile-display-lets-the-blind-perform-3d-printing-and-cad-30597822/).

A simpler Braille printer might be adapted to make 2-D graphs, but may not work for 3-D.

Three Dimensional printers are a possibility provided that you have enough preparation time for creation of the models. They tend to be rather slow.

There are also haptic feedback gloves that might be adapted.

Comment: Thanks, those are useful suggestions.